# Android Developer Tools: XML does not show correctly

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, adt

I recently installed the latest Android Developer Tools, its pretty much just the same as Eclipse Juno (with puprple icon) cept its green now and the Emulator seems to target devices more specifically.

My problem is the when I imported my project back into this new IDE the XML layout doesn't render correctly.  Spinners streach the whole length of the screen, whereas before they were of desired size. But even more bizare is that when I run the program in the emulator, it looks as I originally desired it.

How can I get some order back into the Graphical Layout? Currently it seems redundant because it is not reflecting graphically what my code is telling it and its making it very difficult for me to design my app because I have to constantly check it with running it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is simply: the default layout size in the XML viewer has now changed.

Comment: How/where would I check this?